# How to use scanf with pointer (arrays) inside function?

Tags: c

I still don't know why my code below doesn't work correctly. When I ran, it just let me enter once. Can someone show me how to fix it? Thank you.

I'm using dev C for code and here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void testFun(int *arr) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
        printf("%d element: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", *arr+i);
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[2];
    testFun(arr);
}
```

It only lets me enter once while my desired result is twice.

Comment: This is pretty unsafe, as `testFun` has no way to know if arr is a pointer to a single int, or an array. The idiom for this would be to pass the size as a function argument, such as: `void testFun(int * arr, size_t arr_size);`

Comment: `*arr + i` is equivalent to `arr[0] + i` — which is clearly an integer and not a pointer.  You might have intended to use `*(arr + i)`, which is equivalent to `&arr[i]`.  You should use the subscript notation; it is simpler to understand (and shorter, too).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried it but it still doesn't work

Comment: @SirDarius 
Can you give me an example, for the case like the above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear what problems you were having, but this minor adaptation of your code works for me (and is closely based on what I suggested in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56081172/how-to-use-scanf-with-pointerarrays-inside-function#comment98800784_56081172)).

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void testFun(int *arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("%d element: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[2];
    testFun(arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        printf("%d: %d\n", i + 1, arr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
1 element: 234512
2 element: 872390
1: 234512
2: 872390
```

There are various unfixed deficiencies in the code, including:

- Not passing the size of the array to the function.
- Not checking the result from `scanf()` — it should be one; if it isn't, there's a problem.

I used C99 style `for` loops; if you're stuck with C90, declare `i` outside the loops.

You could also use:

```
scanf("%d", arr + i);
```

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%d", *arr+i);`

You need a pointer to the ith element of the array

So

`scanf("%d", &arr[i]);`

should work

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to know is there any way to use scanf () as my idea?

Comment: @QuốcCường — this code does use `scanf()`, so it isn’t clear what you are asking about.